# Plotting Islands in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot bodies of water on my map and struggling with islands in ggplot2. I understand the right/left-hand rule for exterior/interior rings but there is still a problem going from island to island. The question is how do I plot a polygon with lots of holes/islands in ggplot2? I believe the trick is order, but what order?

Here is the MWE I have built to try and understand and fix the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

ids <- letters[1]

# IDs and values to use for fill colour
values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = c(5)
)

# Example of good polygon and holes
good_positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 5),
  #     shape        hole       hole       hole
  x = c(1,10,10,1,1, 2,2,3,3,2, 7,7,8,8,7, 5,5,6,6,5 ),
  y = c(1,1,10,10,1, 2,3,3,2,2, 7,8,8,7,7, 5,6,6,5,5)
)

# Example of good polygon and holes
bad_positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 5),
  #     shape        hole       hole       hole
  x = c(1,10,10,1,1, 2,2,3,3,2, 7,7,8,8,7, 5,5,6,6,5 ),
  y = c(1,1,10,10,1, 2,3,3,2,2, 7,8,8,7,7, 3,4,4,3,3)
)


# Merge positions and values
good_datapoly <- merge(values, good_positions, by=c("id"))
bad_datapoly <- merge(values, bad_positions, by=c("id"))

# Plot polygons
good_plot <- ggplot(good_datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group=id, fill=factor(value))) +
  scale_fill_discrete("Key")

bad_plot <- ggplot(bad_datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group=id, fill=factor(value))) +
  scale_fill_discrete("Key")

good_plot
bad_plot
```

[image: good_plot]
[image: bad_plot]

Comment: I am still reading and trying to find reasons why. But, one method which works for the badpoly data is to use `geom_holygon`, which you can find [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3522_52420d28ca7d443eae79850822ead5b8.html). You need to assign unique id to each polygon, and run `ggplot() + geom_holygon(yourdata, mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, group = id), fill = "sky-blue")`. This is working on my machine.

Comment: This works perfectly for a single 'holygon'. However, I do have multiple polygons with holes so in a sense need two mappings group e.g. one for polygon and one for holes. I could separate each polygon into a dataframe each and plot them individually.

But type this up to an answer and I will give it the tick.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I have not found the reason why this funny thing is happening yet. But, I am happy to write down the solution above. Let me have a bit of time. I am glad that you are finding your way. :)

Comment: The suggestion is up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, I do not know the reason why we see the discrepancy between the good and bad examples. But, this approach with `geom_holygon` works for the bad position data.

```
library(proto)
library(ggplot2)

bad_positions <- data.frame(id = rep(ids, each = 5),
                        x = c(1,10,10,1,1, 2,2,3,3,2, 7,7,8,8,7, 5,5,6,6,5 ),
                        y = c(1,1,10,10,1, 2,3,3,2,2, 7,8,8,7,7, 3,4,4,3,3)
                        )


### Assign unique ids to polygons
bad_positions$id <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 5)

### geom_holygon
### http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3522_52420d28ca7d443eae79850822ead5b8.html

geom_holygon <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
rule = "winding", ...) {
GeomHolygon$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, position = position, 
    rule = rule, ...)
}

GeomHolygon <- proto(ggplot2:::GeomPolygon, {
objname <- "holygon"

draw <- function(., data, scales, coordinates, rule, ...) {
    n <- nrow(data)
    if (n == 1) 
        return()

    munched <- coord_munch(coordinates, data, scales)
    munched <- munched[order(munched$group), ]

    first_idx <- !duplicated(munched$group)
    first_rows <- munched[first_idx, ]

    ggname(.$my_name(), gTree(children = gList(pathGrob(munched$x, munched$y, 
        default.units = "native", id = munched$group, rule = rule, gp = gpar(col = first_rows$colour, 
            fill = alpha(first_rows$fill, first_rows$alpha), lwd = first_rows$size * 
              .pt, lty = first_rows$linetype)))))
}
})

### Draw the figure
ggplot() +
geom_holygon(bad_positions, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = id), fill = "skyblue")
```

[image]

Comment: I've been relying on geom_holygon for a while now - it works great. However, since updating ggplot2 to version 2.0.0, your code returns error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "eval"
` (at least, I think it's the ggplot2 update which has caused the issue). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @TFinch I have not tried to use geom_holygon yet. I just realized this issue. I think you want to contact the person who created the function. I wish you can get some from the author.

Comment: FYI, Kohske Takahashi pointed me towards some updated code which works with ggplot2 2.0.0 http://qiita.com/kohske/items/9272e29a75d32416ff5e

Comment: @TFinchThanks for that. :)